# Checking the state of the route in the App component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

I am doing my spa app. I finished the user interface, now I need to do the administrative part. The app.vue is the main component of my app. The app.vue is responsible for the template layout of the site.
But another template is needed for the admin panel and I would like the app.vue to also be the entry point for it. The solution that I found seems bad to me:

```html
<div v-if="$route.path.indexOf('admin') !== -1">
     ...
</div>
<div v-else>
    ...
</div>
```

What would you advise?

Comment: It's good to separate user and admin sections to other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how much different your layouts are.

- You can use more robust (and complicated) system as in [vue-enterprise-boilerplate](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/) where each view ([sample](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/src/router/views/home.vue)) chooses its own layout ([sample](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/src/router/layouts/main.vue))
- you can use Vue's [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) in `App.vue` template (see sample below)
- if layouts are very similar and all you need is just different navigation (for example), you can use Vue-router's [Named Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#named-views)

---

1. Extract layout template into its own component (will be very similar to `vue-enterprise-boilerplate` sample)
2. Create component with layout for Admin
3. Use following template in `App.vue` :

```
<template>
  <component :is="getLayoutComponent()">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    getLayoutComponent() {
      // ...logic to choose different layout component base on path
    }
  }
}
</script>
```